# AJAX asynchronous call -- can't return data with callback?

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I have this code below, and I want to return the data in the success function of the ajax call. Of course, if I do async:false and return it directly I get it but I don't want to do that.

If I just run it like it is now, information variable is undefined (if I do async:false, it gets the information, so it isn't the contents of the data that is the issue).

I just don't understand why it isn't working, I googled callback functions and it appears that I am doing it right...

```
function PUT_updateSystem(id) {
    var system= {};
    system= getSystemInformation(name, function(data){
                                var system = data;
                                return system;});

    var information = system.info;

}
// Returns system information
function getSystemInformation(name,callback){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: getUrl(),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT:
Changed my code to what I currently have

I am generating a jsTree with this data, and to create the json data for that tree I am doing the above but putting the information variable into an object and iterating over it to create nodes. The issue isn't with the tree, so I won't include that here. I can even take that logic out to test.

So what is happening,

1. Page starts loading
2. I perform the above
3. Information gets put into a javascript object
4. I iterate over the javascript object.
5. I receive an error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
6. As I'm debugging, I see that it skips over system.done. This makes sense because it may not be done.

Is there a way to wait for it to be done?

EDIT: 
Providing more information

> // IN A FILE CALLED loadinfo.js

```
// Returns system information promise
function getSystemInformation(){
    return $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: getUrl(), // url is defined somewhere else
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json"
    });
}

// IN A FILE CALLED tree.js
// I have other variables from loadinfo.js that are here so they can communicate fine

    $.when(getSystemInformation(), $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
        $(deferred.resolve);
    })).done(function(data) {
        mapCache["system"] = data;
        console.log("defer DONE!!");

$.each(mapCache["system"], function(index, system) {
            var children = doDisplayChildNodes(system.name);
            ...
                    ...
});
```

What I'm doing in this $.each is just grabbing data from mapCache["system"] and creating a "jstree" node. I do a child function to do the same thing, because I have child nodes associated with each system. All of this logic worked because it work working fine when I had the ajax call as "async:false" -- so I won't post that.

I receive the Cannot read property 'length' of undefined  during the $.each. Which is strange because I have a "Watch" set on mapCache and after everything is loaded, mapCache is filled with the correct values. I am using Google Chrome debugging.

Comment: how do you know your callback "doesn't work"? To me it works but it doesn't do anything special.

Comment: what is this function ! ? what is getUrl() do and what url does it take u to , on that url what is the code ?

Comment: The function is defined in the call. It returns the data retrieved. getUrl() isn't relevant to the question and is abstracted from the code -- its simply the url that is used for this request. PUT_updateSystem continues on in my actual implementation, but it is this part that I put in the question that I need assistance with.

Comment: Where is #5 happening?

Comment: When I the page loads, I am running this function and putting the value in the javascript object, then I am rendering the HTML. When I render the html to display the tree I am making, I need to iterate over the values I am getting back (now located in the javascript object) and then I get this error.

Comment: Can you provide that so that we can see what element is undefined?

Comment: I updated it, I tried going the route of using deferred objects but same issue.

Comment: `data` inside your $.when.done isn't what you think it is. When you pass in two or more promise objects to $.when, it's done and fail callbacks get called with a single argument that is an array. (example: http://jsfiddle.net/YhP9F/) The first index is the results from the first deffered, second is from the second deferred, etc. That may explain your length issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You used a callback, however you still used it with synchronous logic rather than asynchronous. Try doing it this way:

```
function PUT_updateSystem(id) {
    var system = getSystemInformation(name);
    system.done(function(data){
        var information = data.info;
        // do stuff with `information` here, not elsewhere.
    });
}
// Returns system information promise
function getSystemInformation(name){
    return $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: getUrl(),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

Comment: Kevin, I find that this answer is best suited toward my issue but I'm just having an issue where I am rendering HTML elements based off of this AJAX call -- when I debug the error in firebug, it skips over 'system.done' which is populating the data that I need for the html. I created a bounty to help get this sorted out.

Comment: @envinyater, regarding your debug problem, have you tried setting a breakpoint within the system.done callback?

Comment: @marty, Yes I have. When I'm debugging, it never hits it but it must hit it after the page is rendered because I set a watch to the object and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

```
function PUT_updateSystem(id) {
    var system= {};
    system= getSystemInformation(name, callbackfunction);

    var information = system.info;

}
//callbackfuncion
function callbackfunction(data){
    var system = data;
    return system;
}
// Returns system information
function getSystemInformation(name,callback){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: getUrl(),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            window[callback](data);
        }
    });
}
```

just instead of `callback(data);`
put `window[callback](data);`
and put the function name as a variable

Comment: I just tried this and it still isn't working. I get an error:   Uncaught TypeError: Property 'function callbackFunction(data){
  var system =data; return data;
 }' of object [object Window] is not a function

Comment: Why are you using global variables for a callback? Yikes.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronyous means that the callback is called when PUT_updateSystem is already done.

The request is made to the server when you call getSystemInformation but right after it's called the function continues to var information = system.info; Before the server has time to respond so system.info; is not set yet. If you have a browser with developer tools IE, firefox with firebug plugin, Chrome all you need to do is press F12. And run the following code you might understand what callback means looking at the messages in the console (alert doesn't work because it pauses JavaScript execution.

```
function PUT_updateSystem(id) {
    var system= {};
    system= getSystemInformation(name, function(data){
                                var system = data;
// you re declare system here so it' actually not set
// if you want to set system in PUT_updateSystem you should
// do system = data; without the val
console.log("this comes last");
console.log("data is returned now",data);
                                return system;});
console.log("This comes first");
    var information = system.info;

}
// Returns system information
function getSystemInformation(name,callback){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: getUrl(),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
console.log("this comes second");
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: the `return system;` should be removed/commented out, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: None if it does anything :) I think the OP tried to get the data in the system variable using closures but then returns the value setting it to a variable and re declaring it. But since it's asynchronyous none of the variables are set at the time the OP expects it to.

Comment: Right, the point i was making is the rest of your code will work as expected, other than the return.

Comment: I copied and pasted the OPs code because it makes no sense, put some console.log in there to demonstrate the execution order. It won't set system at any useful time

Answer (score -2):

You are not doing it right, callbacks do not return any data. There is no wait statement in JavaScript. The asynchronous call is executed and than the JavaScript keeps on processing the rest of the code.

Your code should be

```
function PUT_updateSystem(id) {
    var system= {};

    function processData(data) {
        var information = data.info;
        alert("Do next step");
    }

    system = getSystemInformation(name, processData);
}
```

Break your logic into two steps.

1. Make the Ajax call
2. Process the data in the call back

Comment: If they don't return any data, then what can I do with the variable 'information' -- it isn't going anywhere and I can't return it -- how can I use it throughout my original function?

Comment: You break the function up into parts. The first part makes the call, the second part processes it.

Comment: @envinyater You can't. You really need to figure out how asynchronous code works, it simply doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: @envinyater here is an example of how to do it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests