# Why doesn't the array get populated with the ajax repsonse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Below is my code in a JavaScript file that is included in an HTML file.
When I console.log msg I can see there are 100 items in the array (see screenshot), however dataArray is still empty after the last console.log(dataArray).

I don't get any errors or things like that so it's hard for me to debug this.

```
function loadPosts() {
  var dataArray = new Array();
  var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
  $.ajax({
    url: root + '/posts/',
    method: 'GET',
    success:function(msg){
      dataArray = msg;
    }
  });

  console.log(dataArray);
} 

window.onload = loadPosts;
```

[image: console response]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AJAX asynchronous call -- can't return data with callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732123/ajax-asynchronous-call-cant-return-data-with-callback)

Comment: your arrayList have nested ArrayList . You have to pare it to get actual array, Change this `dataArray = msg;` to `dataArray = msg.d;`

Comment: try async:false.

Comment: You are setting `dataArray` to reference `msg`, and the initial array is thrown out. _You aren't setting the actual elements of the array to anything._

Comment: The code section seems to be ok. It is doing what it was created for. Actually the `loadPosts()` function does nothing except fetching the data using ajax call. You didn't returned the `dataArray` in that function. Didn't used the `dataArray` for any purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3):

Your `console.log` is executed *before* the AJAX request's success handler is called, otherwise it looks correct. You can add a `console.log(dataArray)` after you assign `dataArray = msg;` in the callback to see it.

Answer (score 2):

AJAX is asynchronous by nature, so what is happening is you are executing:

1. Ajax call
2. console.log(dataArray)
3. Success callback

For the desired output you should move your console log into the success handler:

```
function loadPosts() {
    var dataArray = new Array();
    var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
    $.ajax({
      url: root + '/posts/',
      method: 'GET',
      success:function(msg){
        dataArray = msg;
        // act on data array
        console.log(dataArray);
      }
    });
}
```

I would also recommend moving from the success/error callbacks to `Promises`, since the callbacks are deprecated and removed as of jQuery 3.  This would change your code like so:

```
function loadPosts() {
    var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
    return $.ajax({
      url: root + '/posts/',
      method: 'GET'
    });
}

loadPosts().then(function(data) {
    // resolve promise handler
    // do something with your data
    console.log(data);
}, function(err) { 
    // rejected promise handler (failure)
    console.error(data);
});
```

For more info:

[jQuery Ajax Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

[Promise Spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 1):

Check this code below :

```js
function loadPosts() {
  var dataArray = [];
  var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
  $.ajax({
    url: root + '/posts/',
    method: 'GET',
    success:function(msg){
      console.log('First');
      dataArray = msg;
    }
  });
  console.log('Second');
  console.log(dataArray);
} 
window.onload = loadPosts;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you will see that the order of execution.
If you need to treat dataArray after his assignment, in success callback, you need to call a function and pass as argument the new dataArray.

Answer (score 0):

console.log is executed before ajax call is completed. so make asynchronous request.

```
 function loadPosts() {
  var dataArray = new Array();
  var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
  $.ajax({
    url: root + '/posts/',
    method: 'GET',
    async:false,// <--
    success:function(msg){
      dataArray = msg;
    }
  });
   console.log(dataArray);
} window.onload = loadPosts;
```